# RFC 1071 checksum for char array

Tags: c, checksum

I'm having difficulty understanding the following checksum algorithm from [RFC 1071](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1071):

```
The following "C" code algorithm computes the checksum with an inner
loop that sums 16-bits at a time in a 32-bit accumulator.

in 6
{
    /* Compute Internet Checksum for "count" bytes
    *         beginning at location "addr".
    */
    register long sum = 0;

    while( count > 1 )  {
        /*  This is the inner loop */
        sum += * (unsigned short) addr++;
        count -= 2;
    }

    /*  Add left-over byte, if any */
    if( count > 0 )
        sum += * (unsigned char *) addr;

    /*  Fold 32-bit sum to 16 bits */
    while (sum>>16)
        sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);
    
    checksum = ~sum;
}
```

My goal is to take a char array and compute its checksum but I am unsure of what the undefined variables are.  What are the data types of `addr` and `checksum` and/or,  how could I convert a char array to a format that could be used in the check-summing process? I am aware that count is the number of bytes in whatever is stored at addr.

Edit:  So far, I am thinking to convert the char array to an integer, then getting the number of bytes:

```
int char_int = sscanf(char_array, "%d", &i);
int addr = char_int;
int count = sizeof(char_int);
```

Comment: I can tell you that you definitely _don't_ want to use `sscanf(char_array, "%d", &i)`; that converts a written-out number like `"1234"` to binary, whereas this sample code is meant to treat a sequence of N raw bytes as if they are already a sequence of (N/2) 16-bit binary numbers.  I can also tell you that the code shown is very old and does things that are considered incorrect in modern C and therefore you probably shouldn't be using it as a reference.  Unfortunately I don't have a better reference for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the inner loop processes the data in 16-bit increments, `addr` must be a pointer to a 16-bit value, i.e. `uint16_t * addr`.

`checksum` is whatever data type you wish to store the final result in. If you're calculating a 16-bit checksum, it would also be `uint16_t`.

Note that `sum` should probably be `unsigned long`, not `long`. It works in practice because network packets are not generally big enough that the checksum will overflow a `long` (the packet would have to be at least 32K bytes). But if you're writing general purpose code you should code defensively.

You can find an implementation that uses appropriate, portable data types at:

http://www.microhowto.info/howto/calculate_an_internet_protocol_checksum_in_c.html

```
uint16_t ip_checksum(void* vdata,size_t length) {
    // Cast the data pointer to one that can be indexed.
    char* data=(char*)vdata;

    // Initialise the accumulator.
    uint32_t acc=0xffff;

    // Handle complete 16-bit blocks.
    for (size_t i=0;i+1<length;i+=2) {
        uint16_t word;
        memcpy(&word,data+i,2);
        acc+=ntohs(word);
        if (acc>0xffff) {
            acc-=0xffff;
        }
    }

    // Handle any partial block at the end of the data.
    if (length&1) {
        uint16_t word=0;
        memcpy(&word,data+length-1,1);
        acc+=ntohs(word);
        if (acc>0xffff) {
            acc-=0xffff;
        }
    }

    // Return the checksum in network byte order.
    return htons(~acc);
}
```

Comment: I had noticed that solution online as well, but didn't use it as in my case, I am trying to calculate an `int`, and not an `unsigned int` checksum and am unable to import the library for `uint16_6`.  My apologies if I should have specified that earlier.

Comment: @Paradox it is `uint16_t` and it is available in `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: @Paradox If you don't have `stdint.h`, then replace all uses of `uint16_t` with `unsigned short`, and also include `limits.h` and put `#if USHRT_MAX != 65535` `#error "Code below assumes unsigned short is 16 bits"` `#endif` right after the includes.